# open file from external storage

Tags: java, android, android-studio, storage

I am trying to use intent for **open files in external storage** but I don't know why is it showing me toast `could not find item !` I have tried it on different files as well but it do the same , permissions I have used in manifest

```
 @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

     File temp = new File(address,mylist.get(position));

    if (temp.isFile()){
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This is File !!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String  sfile = temp.getPath();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(sfile);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
        
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Open file"));

    }else {

        ref(address+"/"+mylist.get(position).toString());

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have storage permissions in AndroidManifest.xml? If not, you need to add
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` for reading from external storage,
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` for writing into external storage in `<application>` tag in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

can you show sample `address` value (path of the file)? there is a chance that you are keeping your files in some restricted area (e.g. private data folder of your app) and you have to provide `FileProvider` and grant `Uri` access permission to another app for allowing it to use your apps folder. some doc and samples in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing) and [HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider)

assuming `could not find item !` `Toast` doesn't come from your app (I don't see such code) - it may be shown by another app, which just can't get access to `File`

all above assumes that `File` exists in proper directory (both `isFile()` and `exists()` returns `true`) :)